# Select unmatched records from two tables of MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables Table1 and Table2 with some records

id is the common column in both tables and primarykey is set to this column in table1

There are many records in table1 and some of these records (not all) are updated into table2.

Now I want retrieve from table1 the records not updated into the table2.

For example in table1 there are records 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

And in table2 there are 3,4,7,9

Now How can I retrieve these records form table1 1,2,5,6 those not updated into table2

I wrote this query :

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.DATE, Table1.C_NAME, Table1.B_NAME
FROM [Table1] INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SLIPNO <>Table2.id;
```

But the expected result not coming. This query lists all the records repeating each one record manytimes

Can any body give me solution to get the expected result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two columns to find unmatched records in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628337/how-to-compare-two-columns-to-find-unmatched-records-in-mysql)

Comment: @ConradFrix this question is about comparing two _tables_, not two _columns_ in the same table.

Comment: @Fractalizer It's not really a different problem. The answer will be either a anti-join, not in, not exists, and also depending on the RDMS not any, minus, except regardless of if the columns to be compared are on the same or a different table. That said my close vote has long since expired.

Answer (score 12):

```
select * 
from table1
where table1.slip_no NOT IN (select id from table2)
```

Assuming name of common column is `id`

Or you can modify your query as

```
SELECT distinct (Table1.id, Table1.DATE, Table1.C_NAME, Table1.B_NAME)
FROM [Table1] 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SLIPNO <>Table2.id
```

Comment: Thank You But can you give me any other solution actually when i apply this select * 
from table1
where table1.id NOT IN (select id from table2)
 then it took much time I want to get best solution for best efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

A good [reference](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) on SQL joins

```
SELECT t1.* 
   FROM table1 AS t1 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 USING(id)
   WHERE 
       t2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `NOT IN` operator on a subquery for *table2*.

Alternatively, use [MINUS](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php) with two regular queries listing the *ids* in each table:

```
 SELECT id FROM table1
 MINUS
 SELECT id FROM table2;
```

Comment: @raymon MINS is not working could you give some working examples

Comment: MINUS is not supported in MySQL.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger That tutorial is flawed. Have you tried to run their example? It also mentions INTERSECT, which is not supported, either. See [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+minus). Additionally, I couldn't find any mention of a MINUS operator in the latest official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.DATE, Table1.C_NAME, Table1.B_NAME FROM [Table1]
 WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT *  from Table2 WHERE Table1.SLIPNO !=Table2.id );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT id FROM database1.table WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM database2.table)
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT child_table.id FROM child_table LEFT JOIN parent_table ON child_table.parent_id = parent_table.id  WHERE parent_table.id IS NULL`

This *left join* query returns all the records of the child_table when there is no match in the parent_table. When there is no match, all parent_table fields will be NULL.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful here.

Answer (score -1):

`inner join` will not help.  To get unmatched records I tried this:

```
SELECT
 A.ID,A.DATE,A.NAME
  FROM TABLE1 A
WHERE CONCAT(A.ID , A.DATE ,A.NAME)
NOT IN 
(SELECT CONCAT(B.ID , B.DATE ,B.NAME) as X 
from TABLE2 B) ;
```